# Web button only works once, then I have to refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a bit new to web development. As my first project with JS, I decided to create a simple button, on which if someone clicks, it shows a custom popup. But the thing is after closing the popup window, I have to refresh the page to click the button again.

Here is my code so far:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const cloBtn = document.querySelector('.close');
const popUp = document.querySelector('.popup');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popUp.classList.add('open');
  overlay.classList.add('overlay-open');

});

cloBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popUp.classList.add('popClose');
  overlay.classList.add('overlay-close');

})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0%;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn button {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.popup {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.popup button {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 55);
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(133, 131, 131, 0.555);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay-open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.overlay-close {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.open {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: boxPop 0.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes boxPop {
  from {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.popClose {
  animation: boxClo 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

@keyframes boxClo {
  from {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn"><button>Press Me</button></div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="sentence">Hello Nice to Meet You!</div>
    <div class="close"><button>Close</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is, that both button presses adding a class but not removing the counter class. Simplest solution would be the usage of `toggle`. In that case you can bind the same eventListener to both buttons and shorten the JS code drastically:

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const popUp = document.querySelector('.popup');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

btn.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popUp.classList.toggle('open');
  overlay.classList.toggle('overlay-open');
}));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0%;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn button {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.popup {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.popup button {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 55);
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(133, 131, 131, 0.555);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay-open {
  visibility: visible;
}

.overlay-close {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.open {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: boxPop 0.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes boxPop {
  from {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.popClose {
  animation: boxClo 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}

@keyframes boxClo {
  from {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn"><button>Press Me</button></div>
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="sentence">Hello Nice to Meet You!</div>
    <div class="btn"><button>Close</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are adding `open` and `overlay-open` classes and never removing them. So after hitting close, you have `open` and `popClose` on `<div class="popup">`, and `overlay-open` and `overlay-close` on `<div class="overlay">`.

And CSS [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) makes that the second classes apply. You could do as below, having 2 classes  instead of 4. You just need `open` and `overlay-open`.

```js
const btn= document.querySelector('.btn');
const cloBtn=document.querySelector('.close');
const popUp=document.querySelector('.popup');
const overlay=document.querySelector('.overlay');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    popUp.classList.add('open'); 
    overlay.classList.add('overlay-open'); 
    
 });

 cloBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    popUp.classList.remove('open'); 
    overlay.classList.remove('overlay-open'); 
   
})
```

```css
body{
margin: 0%;

}

.btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% ,-50%);
}

button{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn button{
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.popup{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    border-radius:10px ;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:scale(1) translate(-50% ,-50%);
    visibility: hidden;
}

.popup button{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 55);
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.overlay{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(133, 131, 131, 0.555);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay-open{
    visibility: visible;
}
/*
.overlay-close{
    visibility: hidden;
}*/

.open{
    visibility: visible;
   animation: boxPop 0.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes boxPop {
    from {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translate(-50% ,-50%) scale(0);
    }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:scale(1) translate(-50% ,-50%);
  }
}
/*
.popClose{
    animation: boxClo 0.3s ease-in;
    transform:translate(-50% ,-50%) scale(0);
}*/

@keyframes boxClo {
    from {
        position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:scale(1) translate(-50% ,-50%);
        
    }
  to {
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translate(-50% ,-50%) scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn"><button>Press Me</button></div>
<div class="popup">
    <div class="sentence">Hello Nice to Meet You!</div>
    <div class="close"><button>Close</button></div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

***You have to remove old class after each function execution to work it properly.***

```js
const btn= document.querySelector('.btn');
const cloBtn=document.querySelector('.close');
const popUp=document.querySelector('.popup');
const overlay=document.querySelector('.overlay');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    popUp.classList.add('open'); 
    overlay.classList.add('overlay-open'); 
    popUp.classList.remove('popClose');
    overlay.classList.remove('overlay-close')
    
 });

 cloBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        popUp.classList.remove('open'); 
        overlay.classList.remove('overlay-open');
        popUp.classList.add('popClose');
        overlay.classList.add('overlay-close');
   
})
```

```css
body{
margin: 0%;

}

.btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% ,-50%);
}

button{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn button{
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.popup{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
    border-radius:10px ;
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:scale(1) translate(-50% ,-50%);
    visibility: hidden;
}

.popup button{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 55);
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.overlay{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(133, 131, 131, 0.555);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay-open{
    visibility: visible;
}

.overlay-close{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.open{
    visibility: visible;
   animation: boxPop 0.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes boxPop {
    from {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translate(-50% ,-50%) scale(0);
    }
  to {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:scale(1) translate(-50% ,-50%);
  }
}

.popClose{
    animation: boxClo 0.3s ease-in;
    transform:translate(-50% ,-50%) scale(0);
}

@keyframes boxClo {
    from {
        position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:scale(1) translate(-50% ,-50%);
        
    }
  to {
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform:translate(-50% ,-50%) scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn"><button>Press Me</button></div>
<div class="popup">
    <div class="sentence">Hello Nice to Meet You!</div>
    <div class="close"><button>Close</button></div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `toggle` which would be way more efficient. Then youc an merge both functions into the same and end up with less then half of the code.

Comment: yes, that is a better way for this.

Comment: since "open" and "popClose" do different animations, your way is enough for them. "overlay-open" and "overlay-close" just do visibility change, they can use the toggling.